# How to decide on laying out copper area when working with Wifi/RF chips & how to use a guard ring?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, signal, pcb-antenna

I have seen on several designs that the designer has avoided pouring copper around the RF signal lines and all signal lines in general. Such as seen on the following example. He has also added a "guard ring" around the antenna connector.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14_jh3nLSsU&t=1646s

[image]

My question has two parts.

1. Is there an overall guidline on how to decide to use the copper regions? For instance I usually make it so that the top layer is supply voltage and bottom layer is ground. But I am getting a feeling that what I am doing is horrible practice. But my thoughts are not clear on how to use the copper pour tool in a more educated way. My intuition tells me that esspecially around components sensetive to parasitic Inductance I should avoid it.
2. How does the guard ring work exactly? And When should I decide on using it?

If you could recommend a resource/ a book to do further reading on PCB design rules, it would be very appriciated.

Comment: You should really embed images of what you talk about because nobody will bother to watch that video and try and figure precisely which sections you are referring to or which parts of the circuit. Not that hard to do.

Comment: You appear to be mixing up parasitic capacitance and inductance and making no distinction between general copper pour, planes, and stripline/microstrip. You preamble about RF traces but your question asks about planes and pours in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Typically it is not horrible practice. It's not that the practice causes parasitic inductance that could be a problem (because it's always a problem). The practice reduces parasitic inductance by increasing capacitance which is generally good. It is the extra capacitance that could be a problem for sensitive circuits that operate off capacitances of several pF or less like oscillators.

Specifically for traces actually carrying RF though, such as antennas, you do need to pay attention to everything but if it is a chip or module (especially modules) you may not need to be so cautious around most of the component. Check the datasheet guidelines. Besides, 2 layer boards are not the place for RF anyways.

2. Guard rings go around sensitive traces that operate on very low current (typically high impedance inputs but also RF); Currents so low that leakage currents from other nearby things through the PCB dieelectric can interfere. The guard ring tied to GND shorts out these currents before they can reach the high impedance input. Apparently you are not supposed to put soldermask over guard traces since that provides a path around (or over them), as does surface contamination.

Rick Hartley Grounding:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySuUZEjARPY&list=PLlD-hnyodqSf7D9zPVviYaOaDZnWxkDYx&index=21&t=3466s